# nhibernate returning one repeating row

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using nhibernate with a mysql db.  I am trying to do a simple data extraction from one table.  I created my entity and my mappings.  I am able to talk to the db.  It is pulling the correct number of rows from the db table, but each row is a duplicate of the first row in the table.  (I have 51 rows in the table.  51 rows are being returned, but each row is a duplicate).  I have it set to show sql, and the sql is correct.

Here is a snippet of my mapping file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="myAssembly" namespace="MyProject.Models.Entities">
  <class name="myClass">
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="column2" />
    <property name="column3" />
....
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?  Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is "id" really the id of your entity?

NHibernate will return the same object for all returned rows with that id.

Comment: that was the problem - I had my id set up incorrectly - fat fingered it.  I fixed it and everything is working correctly now.  Thanks